# How to enable cross cluster replication in elastic cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, disaster-recovery, elastic-cloud

I created a two node deployment in elastic cloud sometime back. Now I need to ensure my cluster data survives in case of a region failure. To to that, I believe, we need to configure cross-cluster-replication. I have following questions.

1. Cross-cluster-replication option is not available in my Kibana -> Management page.
2. I saw, cross cluster replication needs platinum level subscription. But upgrade license option is not available in Kibana -> management page.

Following link contains the Kibana management page which I expect to see. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.8/managing-licenses.html

Following image shows, what I really see on my kibana dashboard (cross cluster replication and licensing options are not visible )
[image]

Please let me know how I should enable cross-cluster-replication. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From the [subscriptions page](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions):

```
Cross-cluster replication*
...
* Feature is currently not available in deployments on Elastic Cloud Enterprise.
```

Also see [my other thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ccr-on-elastic-cloud/180795/2) on discuss.elastic.co. Elastic is supposed to be working on it, but not sure when it's going to be available.

Comment: But it says it is not available on Elastic Cloud Enterprice. But there are other cloud subscriptions such as gold and platinum. Are we supposed to assume, if it is not available in Enterprice, it is not available in other subscriptions too?

Comment: Elastic Cloud = Platinum

Comment: What do you mean? I already have a cloud deployment with standard subscription.

Comment: When you subscribe to Elastic Cloud you de facto have a Platinum subscription (i.e. with all the Platinum features enabled)

Comment: Well, I want this to be configured in Elastic Cloud (service), not on Elastic Cloud Enterprise.

Comment: Elastic Cloud Enterprise is what Elastic uses to run the Elastic Cloud service.

Comment: anything else needed here to close the question?